# Не подключается css к Spring MVC Security

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Имеется Spring MVC проект + Spring Security. И не удается никак подключить css стиль.
Структура папок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

style.css:

```
h1 {
    color: rgba(255, 1, 90, 0.9);
}
```

jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/style/style.css"/>">
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST CSS STYLE</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

метод в контроллере:

```
@RequestMapping("cssTest")
    public ModelAndView cssTest(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home-views/testCSS");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

При запуске, вижу что стиль не применяется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хэндлеры в конфиг добавил:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Я подозреваю, что Spring Security может блокировать как-то все это дело, поэтому на всякий случай добавляю конфигурацию Security:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and();
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка? И как подключить css? Игрался по разному, в соответствии с тем что нагуглил, но решения так и не нашел. Если что еще нужно добавить в вопрос - скажите. Спасибо всем заранее
UPD. насколько видите, в папке img также есть пару картинок, а в папке audio - пару аудиозаписей. И с ними проблем нет. Они в браузере работают норм.Проблема только с css

UPD 2.

Что приходит в браузере при запросе страницы с css:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что приходит в браузере при запросе страницы с картинкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По линку с css файлом увидел такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема найдена!!!

```
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(),
                new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-16", true, true)};
```

Вот и причина, почему стиль не применяется. В моем конфиге был косяк с фильтром: поэтому и я получал пожеванный css файл, соответственно, он и не применяелся

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276603/how-to-include-js-and-css-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc это решение не подходит?

Comment: @Byb это решение у меня и реализовано. Только у меня конфигурация приложения без xml, поэтому вместо <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/folder/" /> у меня registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

Comment: а можно пример как вы ссылаетесь на изображения или аудио? и во что рендерится `href="<c:url value="/resources/style/style.css"/>"` из установки `css`?

Comment: @siarhei987 да конечно. Ссылка на картинку выглядит так: <img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/reading/a1/1/Emma.jpg" />" alt="Emma" /> в браузере пикча после запуска приложения выглядит так: <img src="/resources/img/reading/a1/1/Emma.jpg" alt="Emma">. А css рендирится в : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/style/style.css">

Comment: учитывая, что всё норм, например, для изображений, можно в devtool браузера, на вкладке network посмотреть и сравнить  какие запросы отправляются для получения ресурса и какой код ошибки приходит, если неудалось получить его. и можно ли напрямую открыть `css` стиль, указав путь до него в строке браузера?

Comment: @siarhei987 я добавил в вопрос что приходит в браузере. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Вы это имели ввиду? Вроде как все нормально? Или нет?

Comment: @siarhei987 огромное спасибо!! Проблема решена! Вы показали куда копать - и она таки вскрылась!!! Я указал в конце поста. Добавьте ответ, чтобы я принял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@siarhei987 в комментариях решил проблему:

```
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(),
                new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-16", true, true)};
```

данный фильтр "пережевал" мой css файл. И получалась следующая ерунда после запуска приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественно тут уже нечему применяться. Проблема решается просто выбрасыванием данного фильтра. Если вдруг кто-то когда столкнется. Еще раз спасибо @siarhei987